# Using Os and Glob to Search and Concatenate .csv Files and Pandas to Create DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, glob

**Problem**

I have multliple directories each with subdirectories. These subdirectories contain .csv files with numerical data in them. I want to us glob and os (not shell scripts) to search two specified directories and then locate specific folders and concatenate them in a format I will describe below.

```
dir1 contains subdir1 contains A.csv 
     contains subdir2 contains B.csv

dir2 contains subdir1 contains A.csv
     contains subdir2 contains B.csv
```

IN BOTH CASES

```
>>> cat A.csv
1
2
3
4
5
>>> cat B.csv
6
7
8
9
10
```

MY DESIRED BEHAVIOUR

Find A.csv in dir1 and find A.csv in dir2, searching every folder and directory, and then merge them.
After merge, create pandas.DataFrame

```
>>> python3 merge.py dir1 dir2 A.csv
# prints df created from out.csv
   x   y
0  1   1 
1  2   2 
2  3   3
3  4   4
4  5   5
>>> cat out.csv
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

ASK QUESTIONS IF NEEDED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to walk through directories and `glob.glob` to search for *.csv files like so:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join
from glob import glob
root_dir = '/some/path/to_a_directory/'
for rootdir, _, _ in walk(root_dir):
    all_csv = glob(join(root_dir, '*.csv'))
    for fpath in all_csv:
        # Open the file and do something with it
```

Comment: I would only like to find the A.csv within each directory, not the A.csv and B.csv joined together. So joining _all_ .csv files is not an option here. I only want to join two specific csv files and none of the rest.

Comment: You can modify your glob queries to do whatever you want. `glob(join(root_dir, 'A.csv'))` for instance would only find the `A.csv` files in each directory. You could make that an input to your script